# How to center the text and icon simultaneously in the TextView?

Tags: android, xml

I have a requirement like this:[image]
And I write the codes below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_green_half_circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/health_consult_ordinary_doctor"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15.3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:text="2次"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15.3dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It runs like this:

[image]

Everything seems to work fine, but when I add a drawable in the `TextView`, it turns weird.Like this:

[image]

And the subsequent codes:(note this: the `android:drawablePadding` is not working)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_green_half_circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/titlebar_consult_v6"
        android:drawablePadding="10.7dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/health_consult_ordinary_doctor"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15.3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:text="2次"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15.3dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So the question is how to center the text and icon in the `TextView` at the same time. I know this question can be fixed by writing an `ImageView` and a `TextView` in a layout, but is there any solutions?
I've searched for a long time on net, but it came to nothing. Please help or try to give some ideas about how to achieve this.

**EDITED:** I have found that: when I set the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`in `TextView`, it works. But when I set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`, it doesn't work. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: take out the padding from textView

Comment: @hackingforgirls do you mean the `android:drawablePadding` ? I said it not worked. :(

Comment: Is your drawable `@drawable/shape_rect_green_half_circle` a .png file?

Comment: @Sabeeh Nope, it's a XML file.

Comment: Well you should settle for `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` instead of nesting it in another `LinearLayout` for performance reasons. Remove the `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: @Sabeeh Thanks for your ideas, but I wanna let the first `TextView` take the rest of its parent layout, and let its content center in it. So I have to use  the `android:layout_weight` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, I have added one more `LinearLayout` and put your `TextView` inside it

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_green_half_circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/titlebar_consult_v6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/health_consult_ordinary_doctor"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15.3dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="2次"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15.3dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome answer! It works, but I wanna know why it works when set the `android:layout_width=wrap_content"`?

Comment: @DysaniazzZ `wrap_content` is used for getting width size which _wraps the content inside view_. whenever you want width size to be grown as per contents inside it use `wrap_content` and if you use `match_parent` the width will be equal to `parent layout's width`

Comment: @DysaniazzZ if you make layout_weight="1" then it will acquire complete width of parent as there is not any another layout inside parent layout except this. if you add one more textview with layout_weight="1" then both texview will have equal width and also they will acquire full width of parent

Comment: Thank you, brother. I give you an up vote and take your answer. :)

Comment: @DysaniazzZ my pleasure :-) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) to achieve a similar result. Something like this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId);
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),
                index , index+1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_swift"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2次"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/titlebar_consult_v6"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_15dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

> add like this

Answer (score 0):

**Edit the answer: Check this: It is working fine**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_primary"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/titlebar_consult_v6"
        android:drawablePadding="10.7dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/health_consult_ordinary_doctor"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15.3dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:text="2次"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15.3dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, brother. It really works. But it isn't what I want. In the first image, it hopes to let the first `TextView` to take the rest of its parent layout and let its content center in it. In your codes, you make the first `TextView` center in its parent layout.